# Why do some search trees place the elements of the sets they represent in leaves only, while some in all the nodes?

Tags: data-structures

[A search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree) is a data structures which represents a set of elements.

[A 2-3 tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933_tree) and  [a B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) are search trees. The elements of the sets they represent are placed only in the leaves of the search trees.

[A binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) is also a search tree. But the elements of the set a binary search tree represents are placed in all the nodes, including the internal nodes.

- Why is there the difference?
- What kinds of search trees place the elements of the sets they represent only in leaves?
- What kinds of search trees place the elements of the sets they represent in all the nodes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what you said, in the three examples you gave, the internal nodes also contain values.

In a [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) for example, all values are located in the leaves, the internal nodes only contains keys.

This is interesting only when the data is separated in a key and some other value (as in a database). This allows more keys to go in the internal nodes, limiting the tree depth. When the nodes are on a slow medium, this limits the time needed to go to the data.

Comment: thanks. binary search tree is different from the other two. A search in a binary tree might not end up in a leaf, but a search in the other two must end  up in a leaf. That is the consequence of what I tried to say in my post. I don't know why binary search tree is different from the other two.

Comment: A search in a B-tree may end up in an internal node. See for example the existence of [Deletion from an internal node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Deletion_from_an_internal_node), which implies that values may be contained in an internal node.

Comment: Thanks. As for the last paragraph in your reply, if a B-tree stores pairs of keys and pointer to a record in internal nodes, will that make it space-acceptable to not store all the elements in the leaves? What is the advantage of storing all elements in the leaves over not storing all the elements in the leaves using the method mentioned in my previous sentence?

Comment: In a strict B-tree (i.e. it contains keys without additional content), each value is stored once and only once: it's optimal. In a B+ tree (i.e. the key has some associated content), some keys are duplicated: it's not space-optimal. But it allows faster retrieval of the data (especially if it is stored on a "slow" medium): it's a compromise between space and access time.